# Ionic 2 undefined value after calling services provider

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I ran into a problem when I initiated a value in my page `constructor` class. I call the `provider` to load data. Inside `service` call I can see data was called but when I called my variables outside of service call it said `undefined`. What happened?

**HomePage.ts**

```
export class HomePage {
  public data: any;
  constructor(private nav: NavController, private auth: Auth, private params: NavParams) {
    this.auth.getProfile().then((profile) => {
      this.data = profile;
       console.log('here i can see data correctly ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
    })
       console.log('here data undefined ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
  }
```

**auth.ts provider**

```
     getProfile(){
   return this.getToken().then((token) => {
   //   console.log(token);
      if (token) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          var headers = new Headers();
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          try {
            this.http.get('http://laraveldev/api/users/get_user?token=' + token).subscribe(data => {
              this.profile = data.json().data;
              //console.log('getProfile ' + JSON.stringify(this.profile));
              resolve(this.profile);
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            this.data = { status: 'error' };
            resolve(this.data);
          }

        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: The first console log is written inside promise resolve callback that is why you are seeing data printed, the next one is outside the callback so by the time that statement is executed your promise might not have been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Your `service` is working properly. What you're not being aware of, is **when** that information is ready to be used (and assigned to you `this.data` property):

```
export class HomePage {
  public data: any;

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private auth: Auth, private params: NavParams) {
    this.auth.getProfile().then((profile) => {

      // Here you are inside the then(()=>{}) so your console log won't
      // be executed immediately. This console.log() will be executed 
      // after the promise gets resolved (it's async)
      this.data = profile;
      console.log('here i can see data correctly ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
    })

    // This console.log() is outside the promise callback, so this line
    // will be executed immediately when you call the constructor,
    // without waiting for the service to send the response (and without 
    // that being stored in the this.data variable). This is Sync.
    console.log('here data undefined ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
}
```

Comment: does it mean how to validate the data from the server and how to manage this?